# segueForUnwindingToViewController in iOS 9

Tags: swift, ios9, unwind-segue

I have a Custom Segue exhibiting a view controller, and then have a corresponding Custom Unwind Segue. This code has worked fine in iOS 8, and is implemented by engendering subclasses of UIStoryboardSegue and implementing the perform method. Then I override the following method in my custom Navigation Controller

```
func segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController: UIViewController, fromViewController: UIViewController, identifier: String) -> UIStoryboardSegue {
    var segue: UIStoryboardSegue
    if (fromViewController is MyViewController.self) {
        segue = CustomSegue(identifier: identifier, source: fromViewController, destination: toViewController)
        //Custom Unwind Segue
    }
    else {
        var unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue = super.segueForUnwindingToViewController(toViewController, fromViewController: fromViewController, identifier: identifier)
        //Normal Unwind Segue
        segue = unwindSegue
    }
    return segue
}
```

In iOS 9, segueForUnwindingToViewController is deprecated. It still works for the MyViewController CustomSegue; however, the default unwind segue no longer works for any other unwind segue. Although calling the method on super returns an unwind segue, the segue never occurs, the view controller is never popped, and the user can never go back to the previous screen. So just to be clear, if I use a regular show segue, the corresponding unwind segue calls the deprecated method, which calls the method on super, and does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If Controller B unwinds to controller A,  then in controller A:

```
  @IBAction func viewController-B-DidExit(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

        let controller = segue.sourceViewController as! viewController-B

  }
```

Then in viewContoller B connect the object you want to exit from to the exit.